# How do I anchor controls to one side in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos, interface-builder

Ok, so I come from programming in Visual Basic on PCs, and now I'm trying to remake my programs on OS X with Xcode, and so far I have been successful. One thing I have noticed, however, is that when I try to resize the window, controls either stay in the same place or stick to one side. In Visual Basic, I used the "anchor" or "dock" properties to decide whether controls would stretch as the window resized or if the stayed to one side. I was just wondering if there is an easy way to do this in Interface Builder. I am using Xcode 4.5.1 and any help I could get would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In IB, click on the file inspector (The first icon), then make sure auto layout is not checked.  Then go to the size inspector (The 5th icon) and make your changes.

[image]
<sub>(source: [fredandrandall.com](http://fredandrandall.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/saveasautolayout.png))</sub>